# Only show launcher on specific workspace?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

Is it possible to only show the launcher on a specific workspace? I would like the launcher for my top left workspace, but none of the others.

I seem to remember seeing an option or setting for this, but now I can't find it now that I need it.